# Scale all items in a RecyclerView of only TextViews?

Tags: android, textview, scale, android-recyclerview

Need to dynamically scale TextSize of all TextViews of a RecyclerView to a single Size.

What I've tried scales only visible items one at a time, giving each TextView different FontSize.

```
itemCount = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildCount();

for (int counter = 0; counter < itemCount; counter++) {
    mTV = (TextView) recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(counter);
    mTV.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, mTV.getTextSize() * detector
            .getScaleFactor());
}
```

`getItemCount()` cannot be used in place of `getChildCount()`, I guess!

Thanks!

Comment: What is this negative vote for?

Comment: Disgrace who down-voted!

Comment: Johnny, in response to your comment, and as pure speculation, the negative vote could possibly be due to your code not being formatted very well. Please keep in mind that a down vote is not a personal attack on your character, it only means that a single person decided that they don't think your question is easily readable, understandable, and/or answerable. Please don't take their opinion personally. Thanks! Edit: I just improved the code formatting for you a little.

Comment: Good Day, @MaximillianLaumeister, SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is:

1)  Add a text size variable in your adapter (let's say `mTextSize`).

2) Add setter method to this variable.

```
public void setTextSize(float size){
   mTextSize = size;
}
```

3) In `onBindViewHolder()` method, you change the text size if necessary

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(holder.textView.getTextSize() != mTextSize && mTextSize != 0.0){
       holder.textView.setTextSize(mTextSize);
    }
}
```

4) When you want to change the size just call :

```
adapter.setTextSize(newSize);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**PS:**

[`getItemCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemCount()):

> Returns the total number of items in the data set hold by the adapter.

[`getChildCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildCount()) :

> Returns the number of children in the group.

So `getItemCount()` will return your whole adapter DataSet size

( `getItemCount()` >= `getChildCount()` )

Comment: ` if(holder.textView.getTextSize() != mTextSize)`
 in onBindViewHolder() makes recyclerView invisible on first start however is visible as you scale on this blank screenand gives desired scaling on textSize. @Rami. Thanks!

Comment: @Johnny You're welcome! You need to init mTextSize variable with the default size when you create the adapter.

Comment: Hi, But TextView gets its TextSize defined in xml. Which is 21sp in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Rami! However, Documentation suggests:  Rely on notifyDataSetChanged() as a last resort.